# Active Reports Table Row Height

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, activereports

Hi I am new with active reports and I am using a trial to find out if I can use it.

I have a table in my report with a header detail and footer row.
The problem I am having is that, I have a description in one of my columns and the description can be 1 or more rows of text.
I can't be set as a fixed height for all the rows because I might have one row with 10 words in it and another row with 50 words.

So how can I make the row height be set auto.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing which you want to make sure is that you are currently using a CPL report rather than FPL report. The fixed page layout (FPL) reports does not allow growing of controls and therefore the table will not automatically grow to accommodate the long text. So I suggest you to try these steps.

1. With the designer open in Visual Studio, go to the Report menu and select "Convert to CPL" option.
2. After conversion, select all the cells inside the table and make sure that their CanGrow property is set to true.

Once you make these changes, the table will automatically grow to fit the long text inside it.

In addition to this, I recommend taking a look at [this](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/AR8Help/AR8_HelpOnlineEN/CPL.html) and [this](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/AR8Help/AR8_HelpOnlineEN/FPL.html) links to learn more about CPL and FPL report types.

I hope this helps.